# Understanding Matrix Calculus

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, neural-networks

Context: I'm trying to figure out how backpropagation works on a variational autoencoder mathematically, by just implementing the backprop algorithm. I'm having trouble figuring out exactly how to do the math to backprop the Kullback-Liebler Divergence part of the loss. However, I think I can get my question answered without any background on deep generative models. [Here](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/vae/main.py) is the code to the loss function in case you're curious.

---

Say I have a function $$KL=-.5(1 + l - m^2 - e^l)$$ $$l= Wx + c$$

Where x is a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^b$, $W \in \mathbb{R}^{a \times b}, b \in \mathbb{R}^a, l \in \mathbb{R}^a, m \in \mathbb{R}^a$. $e^l$ refers to exponentiating the vector elementwise, "1 +" means add one to the vector elementwise, $m^2$ refers to taking the second power elementwise (np.pow).  Lets say I'm interested in $dKL/dW$, and $l$ is the only term that depends on $W$. 
$$dKL/dW = -.5x +.5e^{Wx+c}x$$

What should be the dimension of the final result, and how do I know? Seems like $x \in R^b$, and $.5e^{Wx+c}x \in R^{a\times b}$? Is this right? If so can I add the terms together somehow?

---

EDIT: Am I doing this right?

Let $l = W_{1}Relu(W_{0}x + b) + b_{1}$, find $d\lambda/dW_{0}$: 
$$ \text{Let }dRelu(W_{0}x + b) = dRelu$$
$$dl = W_1dRelu \circ dW_0x $$
$$d\lambda = \alpha (dp - dl) : 1$$
$$= \alpha (p \circ dl - W_1dRelu \circ dW_0x ) : 1$$
$$= \alpha (p \circ W_1dRelu \circ dW_0x - W_1dRelu \circ dW_0x ) : 1$$
$$= \alpha (p \circ W_1dRelu - W_1dRelu)  \circ dW_0x : 1$$
$$= \alpha (p \circ W_1dRelu - W_1dRelu) :   dW_0x $$
$$= \alpha (p \circ W_1dRelu - W_1dRelu)x^T :   dW_0$$
$$d\lambda/dW_0 = \alpha (p \circ W_1dRelu - W_1dRelu)x^T$$

Comment: What does $1+l$ mean if $l$ is a vector? And what's $m$?

Comment: I added some more information to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will use the notation 
$$\eqalign{
B &= C\circ A &\implies B_{ij} = C_{ij}A_{ij} \cr
\beta &= C:A &\implies \beta = \sum_i\sum_j C_{ij}A_{ij} \cr
}$$
to denote the elementwise/Hadamard and trace/Frobenius products, respectively. These products are applicable to vectors as well as matrices.

Given the following variables
$$\eqalign{
 l &= Wx+c &\implies dl = dW\,x\cr
 p &= \exp(l) &\implies dp = p\circ dl \cr
 \alpha &= \frac{1}{2}\cr
 KL &= \alpha(p+m\circ m&-\,l-1) \cr
 \lambda &= 1:(KL) &\implies 1 \in{\mathbb R}^{a} \cr
}$$
Note that the KL-divergence is a scalar. Looking at the Github code that you linked, you neglected to include the "torch.sum()" function in your problem statement.

Hence the scalar $\lambda$ is defined as the sum of the elements of your $(KL)$ vector via a Frobenius product with $1$, the vector of all ones.

Find the differential and gradient of the scalar divergence $\lambda$
$$\eqalign{
d\lambda &= \alpha(dp-dl):1 \cr
   &= \alpha(p\circ dl-1\circ dl):1 \cr
   &= \alpha(p-1):dl \cr
   &= \alpha(p-1):dW\,x \cr
   &= \alpha(p-1)x^T:dW \cr
\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial W} &= \alpha(p-1)x^T = \frac{1}{2}(e^l-1)x^T \cr
}$$
So the gradient has the same shape as $W\in{\mathbb R}^{a\times b}$

A quick review of some properties of the Hadamard and Frobenius products might prove helpful.

Since the Frobenius product is equivalent to the trace
$$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
the cyclic and transpositional properties of the trace
$$\eqalign{
 {\rm tr}(A^TB) &= {\rm tr}(AB^T) \cr
 {\rm tr}(A^TBC) &= {\rm tr}(CA^TB) = {\rm tr}((AC^T)^TB) \cr
}$$
give rise to similar properties in the Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
 A:B &= A^T:B^T \cr
 A:BC &= AC^T:B \cr
}$$
Another useful property is that the Hadamard and Frobenius products commute with themselves and each other
$$\eqalign{
 A:B &= B:A \cr
 A\circ B &= B\circ A \cr
 A:(B\circ C) &= (A\circ B):C \cr
}$$
The matrix of all ones is the identity element for Hadamard products
$$A\circ 1 = A$$

**Update for the ReLu Problem**

Define $$\eqalign{
z &= W_0x+b &\implies dz=dW_0\,x\cr
h &= {\rm step}(z) &\implies H={\rm Diag}(h)\cr
r &= {\rm relu}(z) &\implies dr=h\circ dz = H\,dz \cr
l &= W_1r + b &\implies dl=W_1dr\cr
p &= \exp(l) &\implies dp=p\circ dl \cr
}$$
Then $$\eqalign{
\lambda &= \alpha(p-l+m\circ m-1):1 \cr
d\lambda &= \alpha(p-1):dl \cr
 &= \alpha(p-1):W_1dr \cr
 &= \alpha W_1^T(p-1):H\,dz \cr
 &= \alpha HW_1^T(p-1):dW_0\,x \cr
 &= \alpha HW_1^T(p-1)x^T:dW_0 \cr
\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial W_0} &= \alpha HW_1^T(p-1)x^T \cr
}$$
Replacing a Hadamard product with a vector, by a matrix product with a diagonal matrix is a standard trick for simplifying equations like this
$$h\circ v=Hv$$

Comment: This is really cool! I didn't know you could do matrix calculus like this. So really we needed the frobenius product in order to deal with the summation right? Can I show you a more complicated example I've tried to solve, just to make sure I understand how all of this works? See original post edit.

Comment: @Matt Looks like you are on the right track. It might help you do know that the differential of the ReLu function $r(x)$ is the Heaviside Step function $h(x),\,\,$ so that  $dr=h\circ dx$

Comment: @Matt For your ReLu problem, I obtained $$\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial W_0}=\alpha\bigg(h\circ\Big(W^T(p-1)\Big)\bigg)x^T$$

Comment: Ah thanks! My solution seems similar but I get $$\alpha (W_1 h\circ (p - 1))x^T$$ (after I do some manipulations with my calculations above). How did you get the $W^T$ - that seems key to allow me to get the right dimensions...? I think I'm calculating $dl$ incorrectly, but once again, not sure how to apply chain run to matrices.

Comment: Thanks again!!! This makes sense.